# How to upload Laravel and react app to hosting server like GoDaddy

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, web-hosting

I have a coming soon uploaded on GoDaddy hosting. I just finished creating an app with Laravel API and React JavaScript for UI. I have used `laravel preset react` to use react in Laravel project. I want to know how to upload this project to GoDaddy hosting to make it live.

If I create a zip file and upload it to server, the project size becomes large due to node_modules also being included in the zip.

Below is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "loadjs": "^3.5.5",
        "npm": "^6.4.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
    }
}
```

Below is my webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
mix.browserSync('http://localhost:8000');
```

Below file (index.blade.php) contains react app container:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Project</title>

        <meta name="keywords" content="Organic, Fresh Food, Farm Store">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Vendor CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" type="text/css">

        <!-- Template CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- App Css 
        <link href="{{URL::asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
    </head>
    <body class="home home-4">
        <div class="all">
            <div id="app"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- App JS -->
        <script src="{{URL::asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>

        <!-- Vendor JS -->
        <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/jquery/jquery.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{URL::asset('/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>

        <!-- Template JS -->
        <script src="{{URL::asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/

Comment: Can you find the solution? i am in the same problem.